# astropy make_lupton_rbg returns UFuncTypeError

Tags: astropy

I have three arrays that I read from FITS files that contain images (I can open them with astroimagej. They don't seem corrupted)

```
band = fits.open("band.fits")[0].data
```

```
In : r                                                                                          
Out: 
array([[  40,  608,  829, ...,  652,  297,  306],
       [  70,  886,  786, ..., 1088,  519,  314],
       [  14,  112,  518, ...,  885, 1454,    0],
       ...,
       [1648,  471,    0, ...,   40,  558,   68],
       [1456,  536,    0, ...,   42,  257,  108],
       [ 235,  858,  177, ...,  113,  203,  108]], dtype=uint16)

In : g                                                                                          
Out: 
array([[ 916,    0,  130, ...,  339,   84,  546],
       [   0,    0,  836, ...,    0,    0,    0],
       [   0, 1726, 1712, ...,    0,    0,  505],
       ...,
       [1025,    0,  129, ..., 1485, 2915,    0],
       [   0,    0, 1129, ...,  990, 1815,    0],
       [ 659,    0,  296, ...,    0,    0,    0]], dtype=uint16)

In : b                                                                                          
Out: 
array([[ 916,    0,  130, ...,  339,   84,  546],
       [   0,    0,  836, ...,    0,    0,    0],
       [   0, 1726, 1712, ...,    0,    0,  505],
       ...,
       [1025,    0,  129, ..., 1485, 2915,    0],
       [   0,    0, 1129, ...,  990, 1815,    0],
       [ 659,    0,  296, ...,    0,    0,    0]], dtype=uint16)
```

When I try to run the `make_lupton_rbg` function from the astropy library, I get the error message

```
UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'multiply' output from dtype('float64') to dtype('uint16') with casting rule 'same_kind'
```

Yet it seems to me like every array here is of the same type. What might be going wrong?

I also tried to run the function with one of these arrays repeated three times e.g. `make_lupton_rgb(r, r, r)`, to see if there was a problem with one individual FITS file. I get the same error message in all cases.

Comment: Can you please provide the *full traceback* leading up to the exception?  Everything from "Traceback (most recent call last):"  This information is very valuable for determining where the actual problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

Converting each array to `float64` worked, though I don't know why.